# Can't send MATIC to smart contract using ethers library

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

I deployed my solidity smart contract in polygon testnet(mumbai network).
I tested my smart contract works well in my react frontend except one payable function.

```
function getLotto() payable external {
    require(msg.value == 100000000000000000, "Pay 0.1MATIC");
    ...
}
```

here's my frontend code. it will be called when some button is pressed.
of course, I set the signer and abi in the contract.

```
const handler = () => {
    const options = {
        gasPrice: 800000,
        value: ethers.BigNumber.from("100000000000000000"),
      };
    await myContract.getLotto(options);
}
```

I also tried this code but it also didn't work.

```
value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.1")
```

here's the error message.
[image]

---edited------

```
export class MarioNft {
  constructor(rpc, contractAddr, abi) {
    this.rpc = rpc;
    this.contractAddr = contractAddr;
    this.abi = abi;
    this.isSigned = false;

    this.provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(rpc);
    this.contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddr, abi, this.provider);
    this.baseUri = null; 
  }
  ...

  setContractWithSigner(signer) {
    this.contract = new ethers.Contract(this.contractAddr, this.abi, signer);
    this.isSigned = true;
  }

  async lotto() {
    if (this.isSigned) {
      const res = await this.contract.getLotto();
      console.log("lotto res: ", res); /////
    } else {
      ///////
      console.log("from marioNft class: signer is false");
    }
  }

}
```

```
const lottoHandler = async () => {
    if (metaProvider === null) {
      alert("Need to connect to MetaMask");
    } else {
      if (!marioNft.checkIsSigned()) {
        marioNft.setContractWithSigner(metaSigner);
      }
      
      const options = {
        gasPrice: 800000,
        value: ethers.BigNumber.from("100000000000000000"),
      };
      await marioNft.lotto(options);

  };
```

-------------edited2-----------------

```
const updateEthers = () => {
    let tempProvider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
    setMetaProvider(tempProvider);
    
    // this tempSigner will be used in marioNft.setContractWithSigner()
    let tempSigner = tempProvider.getSigner();
    setMetaSigner(tempSigner);
  };
```

when I print tempSigner
[image]

Comment: Could you provide the code for your contract? Do you have any other payable functions that work?

Comment: @maxall4 I edited! and I have only one payable function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your async lotto function inside of the `MarioNFT` class does not pass on the options object:

```
async lotto() {
    if (this.isSigned) {
      const res = await this.contract.getLotto();
      console.log("lotto res: ", res); /////
    } else {
      ///////
      console.log("from marioNft class: signer is false");
    }
  }
```

So it should be:

```
async lotto(options) {
    if (this.isSigned) {
      const res = await this.contract.getLotto(options);
      console.log("lotto res: ", res); /////
    } else {
      ///////
      console.log("from marioNft class: signer is false");
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks! can I ask other question?
After sending transaction, I got an transactionResponse but I couldn't find the transaction in the polygonscan (of course I changed network to mumbai)

so I resended the transaction but this time it gave me an "replacement fee too low".
I googled it and it's because of pending transaction. but why I can't find my pending transaction in polygonscan? (I didn't set a specific gas fee so gas fee was automatically calculated)

something weird is the transactionResponse's block number was null. 
so I think it was not mined. what should I do to success tx?

Comment: @PudgeKim Try not manually specifying the gasPrice and see if it goes through then or get it from an oracle

Comment: I tried as below.
1. only put value (so gas will be automatically calculated)
2. put value, gasPrice, gasLimit
3. put value, gas, nonce

but it all failed with "replacement fee too low". I don't know what should I do more..

Comment: Your previous transaction is probably stuck try checking if there was an error and if so manually specify a nonce that includes pending transactions so the transaction is not bundled with the last one.

Comment: I also tried putting nonce but it failed. and I can't find my pending transaction in polygonscan (mumbai network). I posted a new question about this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70436158/replacement-fee-too-low-error-when-i-send-transaction-to-payable-function-in-mum

Comment: @PudgeKim Was the nonce the same as the last transaction? How did you specify the nonce and what did you specify it as?

Comment: when I search my transaction in polygonscan, there are 10 transactions. 
so when I use getTransactionCount() method in ethers library, it returns 10.
so I put the nonce 11 (10+1) in options. but it failed.
there's no pending transaction in polygonscan

Comment: when I change address(where transaction nonce is 0) and tested, it works.